# Cannot compare long values using null safe Objects.equals in java

Tags: java, gmail-api

I'm writing a swing application to manage Gmail settings for users in my Gsuite domain, but my method for checking for changes is not acting as expected with long values. It takes an argument with the new settings (in this case vacation settings) and compares it with the previously retrieved settings.

I'm retrieving my settings and clicking the save button without making any changes and my method logs a change. It's seeing a change in the startTime and endTime (both long) attributes where there is none.  I know it's these attributes because when I comment these attributes out it works as expected.

```
private void updateVacation(VacationSettings settings) {
        boolean isModified = false;

        if(!vacationSettings.isEmpty()) {
            if(!Objects.equals(vacationSettings.getEnableAutoReply(), settings.getEnableAutoReply()) ||
                    !Objects.equals(vacationSettings.getStartTime(), settings.getStartTime()) ||
                    !Objects.equals(vacationSettings.getEndTime(), settings.getEndTime()) ||
                    !Objects.equals(vacationSettings.getResponseSubject(), settings.getResponseSubject()) ||
                    !Objects.equals(vacationSettings.getResponseBodyPlainText(), settings.getResponseBodyPlainText()) ||
                    !Objects.equals(vacationSettings.getRestrictToContacts(), settings.getRestrictToContacts()) ||
                    !Objects.equals(vacationSettings.getRestrictToDomain(), settings.getRestrictToDomain())) {
                isModified = true;
            }
        }

        if(isModified) {
            // TODO:Update vacation settings
            Logger.getLogger(MainFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.INFO, settings.toString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: If it's seeing a change, it means there is a change. Someone would have noticed if the JVM didn't compare longs correctly. Why do you use a null-safe Objects.equals() method to compare primitives, which are thus not objects, and can not be null.

Comment: Logger output from my program gives the same values for startTime and endTime. I'm using a null safe operation because getStartTime and getEndTime can return null.

Comment: @user3621877: Don't rely on a logger. Try using a debugger and inspecting the two values. If the `toString()` of both is identical but `equals()` returns false, the values are probably two different classes. Also: a primitive can never be null, so at a minimum you're dealing with `Long` objects, not `long` values.

Comment: Yes, according to javadoc (https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/gmail/v1/java/latest/) both getStartTime() and getEndTime() return a java.lang.Long. Is there a better way to compare these?